# Xamarin Forms, I'd like to touch on the Entry field and the text inside it is clean

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm new in Xamarin Forms, I'd like to touch on the Entry field and the text inside it is clean. can anybody help me?

Comment: do you mean "when I focus on an Entry field I want to clear/delete the text that is already there?"

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm using xaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the Entry's Focused event to trigger an action when the control receives focus:

```
myEntry.Focused += (s, e) => {
  myEntry.Text = string.Empty;
};
```

Comment: Jason, It worked perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a form for a user to fill out and want to show a hint on what they should enter, I'd recommend using a placeholder. This allows you to show some default text and when the user presses the entry, it'll go away. This would be a better user experience since the user would not accidentally lose anything they typed in, but still gets the benefit of the placeholder.

```
<Entry />
<Entry Placeholder="Username" />
```

[image]

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry/#Placeholders

Comment: This won't work if you bind the entry with a numeric (int / double / etc) property, as they don't have "empty" value, but 0 as default, so you won't see the placeholders.

Comment: @Zotyi you could bind to a string in your view model and convert it as necessary. You could still specify a numeric keyboard for the entry field too.